# android storing values in array or list without overwrite

Tags: android, arrays, database, list, sharedpreferences

Am just wondering if there is a way to save data into a text file without being overwritten.

Currently i am using sharedpreferences and it overwrites the data which is okay but coinciding with this, i want somewhere where i can keep record of the value before being overwritten in a list or column form.

So it goes something like this:
60, 65, 70..etc 
The values are stored one after another without being overwritten. I am thinking of doing this locally in a text file which can be read as well.

I am doing this so i can create a stats page or something like that.

I hope someone can help me find a solution.

My code:

```
public class workout extends Activity {

    TextView weightresultText, newweightresultText, difficultyrating;
    Boolean male, strength;
    double newweight, newweight1;
    int weight, age;
    Button button, button4;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.workout);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        weight = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString("storedweight", "Your Weight"));
        age = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString("storedage", "Your Age"));
        male = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("is_male", false);
        strength = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("is_strength", false);

        weightresultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weightresultLabel);
        newweightresultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newweightresultLabel);
        difficultyrating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.difficultylevel);

         if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {AgeCalculation();

             sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();}


        AfterFirstLaunch();
    }

    public void SaveWeight(){
        savePreferences("storednewweight", (Double.toString(newweight)));
    }

//Should only happen on first launch.
    public void AgeCalculation() {
        if (strength == true){
        if (male == true && age >= 18) {
            newweight = (weight * 0.8);
            }
        if (male == true && age >= 30) {
            newweight = (weight * 0.6);
        }
        if (male == true && age >= 50) {
            newweight = (weight * 0.4);
        }
        if (male == true && age >= 70) {
            newweight = (weight * 0.2);
        }
        if (male == true && age > 80) {
            newweight = (weight * 0.1);
        }
        if (male == false && age >= 20 ){
            newweight = (weight * 0.3 );
                    }
        weightresultText.setText(Double.toString(newweight));
        SaveWeight();
            }}

    private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

// On every other launch, it is based on button, the newweight is saved and loaded each time.
    public void buttonClick1(){
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //this gets the current weight based on first time launch.
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            String newweight =  sharedPreferences.getString("storednewweight", "");

           newweight1 = Double.parseDouble(newweight);

            newweight1 = newweight1 + 5;
            //saves value into sharedpreference
            savePreferences("storednewweight", (Double.toString(newweight1)));
            //save to shared preference, and load value on new launch?
            //also store into local database for review later.
            difficultyrating.setText("1");
            button.setEnabled(false);
            button4.setEnabled(false);

           //save this data then on new launch it uses this figure.
            // so first time it creates then uses this figure for future.
        }

    });}

    public void buttonClick4(){
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                //this gets the current weight based on first time launch.
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                String newweight =  sharedPreferences.getString("storednewweight", "");

                newweight1 = Double.parseDouble(newweight);

                newweight1 = newweight1 + 10;
                //saves value into sharedpreference
                //save to text file in array
                savePreferences("storednewweight", (Double.toString(newweight1)));

                difficultyrating.setText("2");
                button.setEnabled(false);
                button4.setEnabled(false);

                //save this data then on new launch it uses this figure.
                // so first time it creates then uses this figure for future.
            }

        });}

    //runs on every other launch
    public void AfterFirstLaunch(){

        buttonClick1();
        buttonClick4();
        //receive value on other launches and show on field.
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String newweight =  sharedPreferences.getString("storednewweight", "");
        weightresultText.setText(newweight);

    }



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For writing into a textFile with overwritten use the following code

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/SO/";

File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        if (dir.mkdirs()) {

    }
}

File logFile = new File(path + "filename.txt");
        if (!logFile.exists()) {
            logFile.createNewFile();
        }

        // BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(logFile, true);
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(fw);


        buf.append("Message");
        buf.newLine();
        buf.flush();


        buf.close();
```

Make sure you have permission defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: So say if in my code, button click 1 was pressed and changed value to 50, and the next time button click 4 was pressed and changed value to 60, would it come up as 50, 60 in the text file?

Should i also put the code you have given into its own class and call it within each button before the sharedpreference overwrite?

sorry for asking just spent so much time on this and dont want to get it wrong.

Comment: You will get both 50 and 60

Comment: Okay i will give this a go and see if it is what i want

Comment: So with your code, im getting errors all over the place not sure why. Unhandled Exception: java.io.IOException

Comment: Did you provide `path` Your folder path??

Comment: Can you give me an example of what this would be on someones device

Comment: but what does the error say? Move your move over it and it will say to add class on top. I believe. It should be `import java.io.BufferedWriter;` & `import java.io.FileWriter;`

Comment: Yes i already have imported them, when i hover over they all say Unhandled Exception: java.io.IOException

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, where you're storing multiple entries of similar data, you'd really want to use an SQL database with a content provider.  You'd just create new rows for each entry.

Comment: Yes i was thinking that but couldnt find any good tutorials to show it so was thinking of alternative of a text file.

A database would work better but have no clue how to implement it into my code.

Comment: @Bimal do you prefer me sharing some good tutorials on SQLite

Comment: Yes please, ill try the text file way first, and then sql way after so i get a good knowledge of both.